# Affinity Designer stroke "curve" limitation?

Tags: stroke, affinity-designer, bezier-curve

If I wish to make an asymmetric stroke with the thickness to one side of the line in Illustrator or Vectorstyler, there is an option to alter the profile of the stroke for this purpose. In Designer, I seem to be limited to changes that run symmetrically along the stroke. Is this correct, or have I missed something?
Edit: Here's one example of the problem. I could shuffle the extra stroke across, but I want the points to snap together.[image]

Comment: you can allways offset then do the same.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Why do you need to make the stroke asymmetric? What are you actually trying to achieve by doing this?  Can you show an example.  There may be another way to achieve it, or just avoid the problem.

Comment: I see, thanks for the update. Perhaps don't have the C shape set with the stroke to the outside of the path. Then you won't have this problem at all.

Comment: I don't use Affinity Designer, but [this example made in Inkscape](https://imgur.com/MlqA9Ww) shows what I mean. This should also be possible in Affinity or almost any vector image editor, including Illustrator, CorelDraw, etc. What you need to do is go into your stroke panel, and set the stroke alignment to the centre.

Comment: Unfortunately there are many situations in my work where I have no choice about having an outline thickness that sits outside the line itself. Thanks for looking guys. Appreciate it!

Comment: @GreenBeetle - if that's the case, then another option might be to switch off snapping, so you can zoom in and move the anchor manually toward the middle of the visible stroke around the C.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by shuffling it across. I always think the beauty of vector art lies in its precision, so I try to avoid "by-eye" adjustments whenever possible.